# getServerSideProps vs getServerSideProps в nextJs

Tags: reactjs, spa, nextjs, next.js

В чем разница между getServerSideProps и getServerSideProps? Я создал [гист](https://gist.github.com/4t4nner/d1631585aa25738723cf9889d80cb34f) на тему. Каждый раз rand разный, при переходе с `shallow:true` на страницу, поведение одинаковое (лог отображается с задержкой на сервере). В мануалах пишут про build при getStaticProps, объясните подробнее.

```js
// page/login.tsx

import React, {FunctionComponent} from "react";
import MainLayout from "../components/layouts/MainLayout";
import {IComponentProps} from "../components/declarations";
import { GetStaticProps, GetServerSideProps } from 'next'
import {randomInt} from "crypto";

export default function Login({children, rand}: IComponentProps) {
    console.log(arguments,rand);
    return (
        <>
            <MainLayout title={'Авторизация'}>
                <p>login</p>
                <p>random: {rand}</p>
            </MainLayout>

        </>
    )
}
export const getStaticProps: GetStaticProps = async (context) => {
    debugger;
    console.log('!!!!!!!!!!getStaticProps - 0!!!!!!!!');

    return new Promise<any>(resolve => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log('!!!!!!!!!!getStaticProps - 1!!!!!!!!');

            resolve({
                props: {
                    rand: randomInt(1000)
                }
            })
        },5000)
    })
};

// export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = async (context) => {
//     debugger;
//     console.log('!!!!!!!!!!getStaticProps - 0!!!!!!!!');
//
//     return new Promise<any>(resolve => {
//         setTimeout(() => {
//             console.log('!!!!!!!!!!getStaticProps - 1!!!!!!!!');
//
//             resolve({
//                 props: {
//                     rand: randomInt(1000)
//                 }
//             })
//         },5000)
//     })
// };
```

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался. [Он запускается каждый раз только в dev режиме](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#runs-on-every-request-in-development). При `npm run build` он запускается только при самом билде. При перезагрузке страницы или переходе - подставляется стянутое при билде.